# What is the most secure way to authorize an user in Android?

Tags: java, android, security

In my app, user logs in with a web service, and web service returns an Authorization Key. After that point, every request user makes is done with this key.

My question is how to securely store this key? I have been storing it in SharedPreferences, but that does not sound very secure to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right using shared preferences is not the approach to follow. You should utilise [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) for any such purpose, it is preferred approach.

> The Android Keystore system lets you store cryptographic keys in a container to make it more difficult to extract from the device. Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable.

And [KeyStoreUsage.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/security/KeyStoreUsage.java) is the example for same.

Comment: That indeed seems like a good approach. Do you have any simple examples using Keystore?

Comment: @TheCook See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/security/KeyStoreUsage.java

Answer (score 1):

1. **Store in cleartext**

   Using cleartext means there is no protection to a user's runtime data assuming the hacker has physical access to the phone.
2. **Store encrypted using a symmetric key**

   Developers are a helpful bunch and they often put the encryption keys in easy to find places like com.packagename.android.util.security.
   Using the
3. **[Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)**

   The Android Keystore system lets you store cryptographic keys in a container to make it more difficult to extract from the device.
4. **Store encrypted using asymmetric keys**

   A safer asymmetric encryption option is to store the private key remotely.

Refer [this article](http://www.androidauthority.com/where-is-the-best-place-to-store-a-password-in-your-android-app-597197/) for more details